# Feature Request - unanswered question

Tags: feature-request

i am a frequent stack overflow user to ask questions and queries, i think there should be an unanswered tab there with `recent, views, newest, votes` that should sort your asked question based on if its answered or not that can help you mark an already answered question or putting a bounty or further searching on the same.

**Update :** pls add this feature its really annoying to do `hasaccepted:0 user:me` when its a small change for SO devs and can be a really good feature for the users.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you're aware of this but you can enter `answers:0 closed:0 user:154325` (that's for `varun`, change the user ID if you're someone else, or `user:me` for just your own questions) into the SO search bar to get all your open questions with no answers.

---

If, as your comments indicate, you're looking for your questions where you haven't accepted an answer, just use `user:me closed:0` and scroll down looking for the answervote boxes that are white-on-green rather than yellow-on-green (your particular questions are all on one page at the moment.

Or better yet, `hasaccepted:0` will give you these. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q= for a list of possibilities.

Comment: thats great, thanks for sharing this i was really unaware of this, but what if it has some answers and is not closed den will it be 'closed:0 user:154325' ???

Comment: `user:me` works too, if you're just interested in *your own* questions. Also, `answers:0` appears to be broken at the moment... Heading off to report that.

Comment: i am interested in my questions that are not closed... any thing for that?

Comment: @varun: `user:me closed:0` gives me all my unclosed questions (thanks for that `user:me` trick, @Shog9, I wasn't aware of that one).

Comment: @PAXDIABLO- tried it but getting list of all questions not unclosed once..

Comment: @varun, assuming you're user 519755 on SO (same profile details), you only _have_ one closed questions, "How to use Rhino". This shows up in `closed:1 user:519755` but not in `closed:0 user:519755`. This is as expected. Are you certain it's closed questions you're looking for.

Comment: @PAXDIABLO - i want the questions which are not marked complete i mean those questions which have dont have any answer accepted for them

Comment: @varun, see the update. You can use `user:me hasaccepted:0` for all your questions without accepted answers.

Comment: kool it worked.. cant it made into some button will be easy for users..

Comment: I'm sure it can. Unfortunately, I don't write the code for SO so I'll have to leave it with Joel et al :-)

Comment: @PAXDIABLO - so can you please propose as a new suggestion